# How can I config nginx to send multiple POST requests in one connection

Tags: nginx

I am developing an Upload application.

I use Google Chrome  to upload a big file (GB) and  use nginx to pass the file to my backend application.

I use Wireshark to find that Chrome send the file in one connection with multiple POST requests.
But nginx will split every POST request then send it in different connection to backend application.

How can I config nginx to make it send all the POST requests in one connection, not per POST request one connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh my god, it's pathetic!

The solution is just enable Nginx upstream keepalive.

Operations to enable [upstream keepalive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html).